# Add current date to dropdown if doesn't exist in database

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have a table with a date selector that I am trying to add a current date option UNLESS there are rows already present with that date.

Here is how it looks:

[image]

Today is the 25th yet it shows the date for the 20th since there are rows present with the 07/20/2013 date in it. How would I do it so it shows the current date?

Here is the code

```
<div class="lookup">
<form action="index.php" method="get">
<select name="exam_date" ONCHANGE="location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;" id="type" class="neutral">
<?php
$sql_gdate    = "SELECT distinct pat_date from patients ORDER BY pat_date DESC";
$result_gdate = mysql_query($sql_gdate);
while ($row_gdate = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_gdate)) {
    echo '<option value="?exam_date=' . $row_gdate['pat_date'] . '"';
    IF ($exam_date == $row_gdate['pat_date']) {
        echo 'selected="selected"';
    } else {
        echo '';
    }
    echo '>' . $row_gdate['pat_date'] . '</option>';
}
?>
</select>
</form> 
</div>
```

Comment: you will need to pass your results to a function that process it (checking for missing dates and injecting it in)

Comment: `($row_gdate['pat_date'] == null) ? $date = date('Y-m-d') : $date = $row_gdate['pat_date'];` Then use `$date`. If you just want it to show up in the HTML.  Or do you mean you want to populate the table?  Your question isn't that clear.

Comment: I want it to populate the drop down with the current date even if no rows are present with that date. Just to make it look nice. Incase there are rows with the current date it already automatically shows it. But when there are none it skips down to the newest date with rows that have that date in it. Where would I add that code to? into the `IF ( )` statement that I have set up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following SQL to modify your table so that the dates are stored properly -

```
ALTER TABLE patients
    ADD COLUMN pat_date_new DATE NOT NULL;
UPDATE patients SET pat_date_new = STR_TO_DATE(pat_date,'%m/%d/%Y');
-- NOW CHECK THAT THE VALUES ARE STORED CORRECTLY BEFORE DROPPING THE OLD COLUMN

ALTER TABLE patients
    DROP COLUMN pat_date,
    CHANGE COLUMN pat_date_new pat_date DATE NOT NULL;
```

Once the dates are stored in the correct format you will be able to use the query posted previously -

```
SELECT DISTINCT pat_date FROM patients UNION SELECT CURRENT_DATE ORDER BY pat_date DESC
```

You will need to change the format of the date received form your datepicker. You can do this easily in either PHP or SQL -

```
INSERT INTO `patients` (`pat_date`) VALUES(STR_TO_DATE('07/25/2013','%m/%d/%Y'));
```

**NOTE**: You should not be using the deprecated mysql_* functions. Use either [mysqli_*](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Comment: Awesome, one last thing, where I need to change the information  `$date= mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['pat_date']));`

Then I just directly insert that $date into the database, how should I edit that line to make it work with the last code you gave me?

Comment: Should It look something like this? `$date= STR_TO_DATE('$_POST['pat_date']','%m/%d/%Y');`

Comment: No, STR_TO_DATE is a MySQL function, so it should be part of your SQL query. There is a similar method in the PHP DateTime class - `$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d-Y', '07-25-2013');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');`

Comment: But it gets inputted into the mysql query right away using the $date variable name.

Comment: So, use the PHP example that I posted in the previous comment.

Comment: Works perfect on that. One last thing, I have data and rows with the value **07-25-2013** but when I load the page it doesn't show the data, I have to manually set the date in the GET for it to show. It shows the date in the drop down but doesn't automatically get the information from it. Current without GET **/index.php?exam_date=2013-07-25**  http://i.imgur.com/WSgapw3.png -- And how it looks when its set: http://i.imgur.com/QygNnUv.png

Comment: Set a default value for your exam date if nothing is passed in the query string. Something like `$exam_date = ($_GET['exam_date'] ? $_GET['exam_date'] : date('Y-m-d'));`

Comment: I did set it up here but it doesnt seem to work `if(isset($_GET["exam_date"]))
{
$exam_date= mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_GET['exam_date']));
//$exam_date = $_GET["exam_date"];
}
else
{
$exam_date = date('Y-m-d');
}`

Comment: Please add your code in to your original question so that it can be formatted correctly. It makes it much easier to read.

Comment: I am glad you got it working. Please remember to accept one of the answers when you are done.

Answer (score 1):

```
select dt from
(
SELECT distinct pat_date as dt from patients 
union
SELECT CURRENT_DATE() from dual
)
ORDER BY dt DESC
```

Comment: How does that make sense? If you could explain that to me please.

Comment: this takes your current query and makes sure there is also included todays date

Comment: dt is just a column alias.

Comment: Okay so I would insert that whole code into the `$sql_gdate = " ";` am I correct?

Comment: There is no need for the outer select - `SELECT DISTINCT pat_date FROM patients UNION SELECT CURRENT_DATE ORDER BY pat_date DESC`

Comment: Thanks, but now it doubles the dropdown value since I already have the data for **7/25/2013**. i want it to show ONLY when I dont have any rows with the **7/25/2013** in it. I just added 5 random rows with the date. Picture http://i.imgur.com/wl7KwLK.png

Comment: It appears that you are storing pat_date as a string? Is that true?

Comment: As a string yes, because I manually select it from the sidebar you can see in the picture. a calendar pops up to select the date, its so you can create appointments for later dates.

Comment: I suggest you fix that before you go any further. Storing the date as a string in your database is very inefficient.

Comment: How should I store it then? I cant store it as a datestamp if I get the dates manually from a date selector.